# ios and ios_base class for stream formatting

Tags: c++, iostream

I found there is two ways to setf()/unsetf() for the iostream, that is
(1) ios and (2) ios_base.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout.width(5);
    cout << 123 << endl;

    cout.setf(ios::adjustfield); // (1) using ios::
    cout << 123 << endl;

    cout.width(5);
    cout << 456 << endl;

    cout.setf(ios_base::adjustfield); // (2) using ios_base::
    cout << 456 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

What's the difference of them when I would like to change the format of the ostream;

Which do you use normally in changing the format?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The constants are actually defined in `std::ios_base` but `std::ios` (well, actually `std::basic_ios<cT, Traits>`) is derived from `std::ios_base`. Thus, all members defined in `std::ios_base` can be accessed using `std::ios`.

The class `std::ios_base` contains all members which entirely independent of the stream's template parameter. `std::basic_ios<cT, Traits>` derives from `std::ios_base` and defines all members which are common between input and output streams.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In your reply, do you recommend to use "ios" not "ios_base"?

Comment: Most of the time I'm using `std::ios_base` for the members actually defined in `std::ios_base`: this way anybody looking up the definition doesn't have to find the documentation by walking up the inheritance chain.

Comment: Thank you again. I see that for the members defined in std::ios_base, you use ios_base.