# Possible to clear individual error state flags for a stream?

Tags: c++

For example, can I clear just the failbit flag? ios::clear seems to clear all the flags, or set individual ones. ios::setstate also seems to set individual flags but not clear them.

The reason I am asking is because I don't want to clear badbit if it is set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clear just the `failbit` for e.g. `std::cin`, you can use

```
std::cin.clear(std::cin.rdstate() & ~std::ios::failbit);
```

You need the bitwise AND between `rdstate()` and the negation of the flag bit you want to clear, otherwise you are just setting that flag. If you think about it, it makes sense: the `rdstate()` returns the state of the set flags, then AND-ing it with the negation of the flag you want to erase just erases that flag and nothing else is modified.

Comment: Thank you! How did you learn this? Also, does it matter if I use std::ios::failbit or std::ios_base::failbit?

Comment: I remember reading about streams etc in [The C++ Standard Library](https://www.amazon.com/Standard-Library-Tutorial-Reference-2nd/dp/0321623215/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1485232621&sr=8-1&keywords=the+c+standard+library), it's a great and very detailed C++ reference. Regarding the second question, the `ios` is derived from `ios_base` (in which the constants are defined), so both notations are equivalent. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19128054/3093378) for more details.