# How to unsetf ios::fixed without using namespace std

Tags: c++, namespaces, manipulators

Soooo... I want to write this code *without* `using namespace std;` because I recently learned "polluting the global namespace" is bad practice.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std; // bad practice, trying to remove

int main() {
    std::ofstream outFile; // instead use explicit namespaces

    /* lots of code */

    // eventually I set some manipulators
    outFile << std::fixed << std::showpoint << std::setprecision(2);

    /* more code */

    // later I wish to unset fixed
    outFile.unsetf(ios::fixed); // <-- this part
```

I was doing fine without the namespace until this `outFile.unsetf(ios::fixed)` which works only if I use the namespace std. I have attempted to write the following variations without using the namespace:

```
outFile.unsetf(ios::fixed)
outFile.unsetf(std::fixed)
outFile.unsetf(ios::std::fixed)
```

Is `ios` a namespace inside of the `std` namespace? Then, this next one makes the most sense to me but also does not work.

```
outFile.unsetf(std::ios::fixed)
```

Primarily, I would like some help fixing this line using explicit namespaces. Secondarily, if there's a critical knowledge gap I need to close, some help identifying it and maybe some keywords to go look up would be helpful.

Comment: The problem with "the_things" is that it probably hides a missing included file. When I do the legwork you should have done into making this a [mcve], the code compiles successfully http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b46fbd08ba65920

Comment: Bad assumption. Concept so basic, I tried to reduce the noise. I do see `std::ios::fixed` does in fact work and it is just one of those moments where "I swear I tried that and it didn't work." But alas, you are correct, this code does in fact compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `std::ios_base::fixed`:

```cpp
outFile.unsetf(std::ios_base::fixed);
```

Comment: Thanks - apparently `std::ios` is derivative of `std::ios_base` so it works the same way. Note to self - related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128054/ios-and-ios-base-class-for-stream-formatting .